# MySQL Join and Default

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm still very new to SQL queries and can't quite figure this one out.

I have two tables, one table I'm running a general `SELECT ... WHERE`, super easy SQL statement.

Ex:

```
SELECT * from maindata where somedata4 LIKE "%data4.%"
```

This gives me back a list of all 6 entries below, however I want an additional column to show me if the current `userdata.userId` has a matching row and to include the amount column of that. If it doesn't have that row to default to a value of 0.

**Table: maindata**

```
id | somedata | somedata2 | somedata3 | somedata4
_________________________________________________
1  | data1.1  | data2.1   | data3.1   | data4.1
2  | data1.2  | data2.2   | data3.2   | data4.2
3  | data1.3  | data2.3   | data3.3   | data4.3
4  | data1.4  | data2.4   | data3.4   | data4.4
5  | data1.5  | data2.5   | data3.5   | data4.5
6  | data1.6  | data2.6   | data3.6   | data4.6
```

**Table: userdata**

```
id | itemId | amount | userId
_____________________________
1  | 6      | 4      | 1
2  | 4      | 4      | 26
3  | 4      | 2      | 1
```

It should search table **maindata** for `WHERE somedata4 LIKE "%data4.%"` and on each of those entries look in table **userdata** for `userdata.amount` with `maindata.id = userdata.itemId WHERE maindata.userId = 1`

Here's what I currently have for SQL

```
SELECT m.*, IFNULL(u.amount,0)
from maindata m
LEFT OUTER JOIN userdata u ON m.id = u.itemId
WHERE m.somedata4 LIKE "%data4.%"
```

What I'm missing is the filtering of only amounts from `userdata.userId = 1`, I want the entire list to show as it is in that query.

Expected Results:

```
id | somedata | somedata2 | somedata3 | somedata4 | amount
__________________________________________________________
1  | data1.1  | data2.1   | data3.1   | data4.1   | 0
2  | data1.2  | data2.2   | data3.2   | data4.2   | 0
3  | data1.3  | data2.3   | data3.3   | data4.3   | 0
4  | data1.4  | data2.4   | data3.4   | data4.4   | 4
5  | data1.5  | data2.5   | data3.5   | data4.5   | 0
6  | data1.6  | data2.6   | data3.6   | data4.6   | 2
```

Comment: your query should be returning NOTHING, since you you're using `m.id` and have no tables aliased/named as `m`. maybe it should be `maindata m`?

Comment: What does this mean "but I can't filter down on it on an additional `WHERE`"?

Comment: Agreed with the comments above. I edited out real data with fake data and missed that part. it should just be m and u for this example

Comment: see my comments below for the "additional `WHERE`" explination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the SQL Query I was looking for (I think):

```
SELECT m.*, IFNULL(u.amount,0) AS "Amount"
FROM maindata m
LEFT OUTER JOIN userdata u ON m.id = u.itemId AND userid = 1
WHERE m.somedata4 LIKE "%data4.%"
```

It's giving me the desired results listed above, I just don't know if it's the most efficient way of handling this request.

[SQLFiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dc82/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.*, IFNULL(u.amount,0) from maindata m LEFT OUTER JOIN
  userdata u ON m.id = u.itemId WHERE m.userId = 1
```

Comment: It's missing the additional where.
It should search table `maindata` for `WHERE somedata4 LIKE "%data4.%"` and on each of those entries look in table `userdata` for userdata.amount with `maindata.id = userdata.itemId WHERE maindata.userId = 1`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution but i am not sure if this is what you are looking for. Let me know.

**-------EDIT--------**

Now I'm sure about what you are looking for. I had just a couple of minutes so I didn't really optimized the code, but this seems to work except for the order of the fields, that can't be really modified since we're operating in two different sets of results.

By the way, this is the query

```
SELECT m.*, '0' as amount
from maindata m
left outer JOIN userdata u ON m.id = u.itemId
where (u.userid is null) and m.somedata4 LIKE '%data4.%'

UNION

SELECT m.*, u.amount
from maindata m
inner JOIN userdata u ON m.id = u.itemId
where u.userid = 1 and m.somedata4 LIKE '%data4.%'
```

and this is the [updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb88b/55)

Hope this helps.

Comment: That gives back only 2 lines instead of all 6 with the 4 that don't have values being `amount = 0` updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb88b/4

Comment: I also added my expected results above to better describe the output expectations